# Implementing a wildcard redirect on subdomains htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect, cpanel

I have a multi-location site that utilizes subdomains, from which they share exactly the same folder structure as the primary domain.

Now I am migrating to a new domain scrapping the subdomains and converting them to folders (on the new domain) so redirects should look something like this:

**location.example.com** (redirects to ->) **new-example.com/location**

**location.example.com/service** (redirects to ->) **new-example.com/location**

I set up redirects for the primary domain, its service page, and the same goes for the subdomains.

```
Redirect 301 /service/ https://new-example.com/service
```

and

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^location.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ new-example.com/location%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NC,L,QSA]
```

My problem is that the subdomain's subfolders (service page) are not being redirected to the new location page. And I think it's being caught by this line:

```
Redirect 301 /service/ https://new-example.com/service
```

What should I do to implement a wildcard redirect on the subdomains going to a new URL, without affecting the primary domain's service pages / subfolders?

Comment: Please fix your examples, resp. clarify the situation. Those make it sound as if you wanted to redirect all requests to `new-example.com/location`, discarding the original path, but then your `Redirect` directive suggests something different.

Comment: actually, that was the question, given that I already have the RewriteEngine block, do I  keep the `Redirect` directive?

Comment: If you want to redirect from `location.example.com/service` to `new-example.com/location`as you said, then it does not make much sense to begin with.